# Java equivalent of: String.format("{0:D9}", Result);

Tags: java

Does anyone know the Java equivalent of the C# format of:

```
String.format("{0:D9}", Result);
```

Here what it does:  http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Data-Types/doublenumberformat0C0D90E0F30N0X0x.htm

This little problem is killin' me...

Comment: That's not a very good example of what it does. Could you **describe** what you want the effect to be? Or at least link to some documentation that makes it clear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I understand the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString) `D9` means "format as a decimal number with at least 9 digits, left-padding with 0 if necessary).

The equivalent in [Java format Strings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) would be `%09d`:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%09d", 1234));
```

This prints

```
000001234
```